# Unable to get file name Uning UIImagePickerController

Tags: uiimagepickercontroller, ios11.3, swift4.2

I am newbie in swift i stuck in a little problem. I am attaching image using UIImagePickerController. Good thing is that successfully attached an image but unable to get attached file name. I tried several solutions like

UIImagePickerControllerImageURL,         UIImagePickerControllerImageRefrenceURL,
UIImagePickerControllerPHAsset but didn't succeeded Please guide me and thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

As per your question, you will get your point in the `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo` method , where you get info object in above method in that included all info about your file.

Check below code:

```
let imageURL = info[UIImagePickerControllerImageURL] as! URL
print(imageURL.lastPathComponent)
```

Happy coding.

Comment: thanks for answer tried it but lastPathComponent gives some id related to image not the name of image this method not gives any satisfying output

Comment: you will get name by this info only . checkout this, if let path = info[UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL] as? NSURL {
                let url = path.absoluteString
                //Continue whatever you want
                let componentString = (url )?.components(separatedBy: "&ext=")